# Best(simplest) method or framework to track user's history in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, breadcrumbs

I've used SWFAddress, but it seems full of quirks, and not fully implemented in all browsers.
I don't necessarilly need deep linking, rather I simply need to track a users history as he she travels thru a flash application (user stays in application).

Any suggestions, desgin pattern recommendations, code examples?

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar and I used an array/vector to trace their path.

Each section of my flash file I assigned a code (say, "Section-1" or "Section-name") and I would add it to the array.

```
var playerPath = new Array();

// when they get to the new section

playerPath.push("Section-name");
```

When they go back a step I just remove the last item.

```
playerPath.pop();
```